# Saving a bunch of integers to file android

Tags: android, storage, internal

So I have a bunch of EditText fields that I need the user to enter in. After this is done I want to save all the input-values to a file and make them loadable by clicking on them in another tab.

I'm kinda lost though.

I have about 5 EditText fields that I convert to ints (they are inputting ints) and then calculating different values from them. I want to save these values in int form. How do I achieve this easiest way? I'm only finding how to save strings.

If I want to save every click on the "calculate" button to a different file (if the user changes a input value and clicks calculate again I want a second file to be made with those values). How do I achieve creating a lot of files that are different (or the same if the button gets spammed).

Thirdly, how can I show what files there are to be loaded from the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the text of all the edittext you have to use following code:

```
// write text to file
 public void WriteBtn(String finalString) {
 // add-write text into file
 try {
 FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
 OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
 outputWriter.write(finalString.toString());
 outputWriter.close();

 //display file saved message
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 }
```

To read the text from file following code can be usefull:

```
// Read text from file
 public String ReadBtn() {
 //reading text from file
 try {
 FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
 InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

 char[] inputBuffer= new char[100];
 String s="";
 int charRead;

 while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
 // char to string conversion
 String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
 s +=readstring; 
 }
 InputRead.close();

return s; 
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
return "";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yes but this only works for strings? 
I never convert the EditTexts to strings but to ints. Is it really necessary to convert them both ways...? Can't I save the ints directly

Comment: why can't you convert it to string while storing and on retrieval you convert that to int?